# How to reload datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF application where I want to select item from datagrid and pass to textbox. after that on add button selected gridrow must be remove. I have a stored procedure to remove from table. And at same time reload the table in same datagrid.

I tried this code

```
private void refresh()
{
    datagrid1.items.refresh();
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object Sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
    refresh();
}

private void datagrid1_SelectionChange(object Sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
     var selectedrow = datagrid1.selectedItem as datarowview;
     var id = selectedrow["Tagid"]; // Here I get error that object reference is not set is an instance of an object 
    string s = conver.tostring(id);
    txttextbox1.text= s;
}
```

After click add button, I get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I'm guessing that the error occurs in your **referesh()** method. What exactly is null? Is it the **datagrid1** or the **datagrid1.items**? Also [please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it would be easier if you look at mvvm, there you just handle the collection and the datagrid is "refreshed" automatic with the right bindings :)

Comment: @  Mike eason-  actually datagrid1 not relode or refresh by using datagrid1.items.referesh(); In refresh() I just do datagrid1.items.referesh();

Comment: @blindmeis- I did not use mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forcing your selected item as datarowView which it is not, cast to correct type

```
var selectedrow = datagrid1.selectedItem as DataRowView
```

`SelectedItem` is type of object that is bound to grid not row

Try doing this

```
private void datagrid1_SelectionChange(object Sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
    var selectedItem = datagrid1.selectedItem as MY_Custom_Object;
    var id = selectedItem.Tagid; 
    string s = Convert.ToString(id);
    txttextbox1.text= s;
}
```

Comment: @ Muds - "My_custom_object" Is which datatype?

Comment: its same data type that you bound to your grid,.... I am assuming dataGrid1 has an itemsource ... itemsource is usually IEnumerable<T>.. so whatwver your list is .. that's your datatype...

Comment: hint: its the datatype that has Tagid

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer. But still not get that "My_Custom_object" I am new for wpf. Will you plz elaborate in detail

Comment: <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionChanged= "Datagrid1_SelectionChange"  SelectionMode= "Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag Id" Binding="{Binding 'TagId'}" Width="50" />       
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

Comment: where do you set itemssource ?

Comment: which object contains tagid ?

Comment: Create Seperet Fuction To aad data in datagried   'private void adddata() { ds = obj.update("SpName"); dt= ds.table[o]; datagried1.itemssource= dt.defaultview;}'

Comment: what is datatype of data ?